# AZURE Skytap Oracle db environment showing block corruption

Tags: azure, oracle

We are seeing redo, undo and datafile block corruptions when we restore using RMAN into Azure Skytap from our source servers. This is a reoccurring issue. As soon as we fix it in one place, it sems to spring up in another. Has anyone else seen reoccurring block corruptions in Azure Skytap when running Oracle (11g) AIX emulation? If so what was the cause and more important, how did you fix it?